# Why is my old wall receptacle randomly flashing/flickering orange INSIDE the outlet? (GIF included)

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I noticed the top outlet of this old wall receptacle randomly flickering an orange light inside the outlet. I've included an animated GIF to show what it looks like. There isn't any buzzing/sizzling sound, just this strange blinking at sporadic intervals, sometimes several seconds between blinks, sometimes several blinks within a second.

Has anyone ever seen this before? And is this something I should be worried about?

[image]

Comment: The only thing that will make an outlet flash like that is flames or sparks, which will lead to flames.  Turn off the breaker for that outlet now, and replace that outlet when you have time.  Why have you not turned off that breaker yet.  I said now.

Comment: that orange glow is the tell tale signature of a neon lamp. It was/is a lighted outlet, but as the neon ages it flickers. Nothing to be concerned about. My grandma has one just like it, with the "dimples" on it's "cheeks", been a while since i've seen one...

Comment: neon lamps start to flicker when old ... if you shine a bright light on a flickering neon lamp, then it usually lights up without flickering ... the bright light gives it a bit of extra energy that it needs to light properly

Answer (score 4):

##### TURN OFF THE BREAKER! NOW!

There are only three reasons why a receptacle should produce any light:

- It is a GFCI or AFCI receptacle with indicator lights. *But this is an ordinary receptacle.*
- It has a built-in nightlight of some sort. *I have seen switches like that, but not receptacles, but in any case that does not appear to be the case here.* If it turns out that this *is* an actual light by design then it is not inherently bad. However, the flickering could still be a sign of a loose connection - e.g., between the light source and the rest of the receptacle, and that can lead to problems even if this light is actually OK. **Can't tell for sure without taking this apart.**
- Something is **WRONG**!

I think it is a pretty safe bet here that something is wrong. Light in an electrical device that is not supposed to produce light is **Not a Good Thing ™**. Light means heat, heat means fire - either now or in the future.

- Turn off the breaker. If the light show doesn't go away then you have serious problems.
- Assuming the light show does go away with power off, carefully open up the receptacle.
- Take pictures of the existing wiring so you know how to connect a new receptacle.
- Remove the bad receptacle.
- Check the wiring for damage. There could be anything from no damage at all to burnt insulation or other problems. If there is anything out of the ordinary and it isn't totally clear how to fix it, post pictures and don't replace the receptacle until everything is resolved.
- Assuming the wiring is in good condition (electrical tape can help if it is a little messed up, but not if it is falling apart), install a new receptacle.
- When you install the new receptacle, match the wiring configuration to the old receptacle *and* make sure that the tabs on the side are on (default) or off the same as the old receptacle. If you are not sure, post pictures of the old receptacle and we'll figure it out.
- For a new receptacle, you can get the $0.99 bulk type, but I recommend spending a few dollars more for a "commercial grade" receptacle [like this Leviton from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Commercial-Grade-Duplex-Outlet-White-R62-CBR15-00W/202066707):

[image: Leviton 15A]

which has "screw-to-clamp" so you can insert wires under a plate under the screw which is easier for novices than making a hook around the screw and much more reliable than "back stab" connections.

Comment: red hot wouldn't blink, it would fade at most. And an arc would be cold blue...

Comment: @dandavis I don't know *exactly* what type of problem would cause this. But a receptacle is normally a sealed device (from the back, not from the front) so any light coming out if it isn't a GFCI (indicator light) or similar can't be good.

Comment: it's harmless, just a neon glowing outlet/nitelight thing. Surely you've seen the sporadic flicker of an old neon light tube in other, less concerning contexts.

Comment: I have. But in a switch, not a receptacle. That is my 2nd option listed. I'll revise a bit in case that is what is really going on.

Comment: Some additional notes: 1) There isn't any heat being emitted from that outlet, and 2) This is my roommates house, who says it was built in the late 70s' and says he recalls it doing that and believes it might be a nitelight. It's the nightstand outlet, so that may very well be it, per dandavis's comments. I'm open to further answers/comments but considering it's not hot or making sparking sounds, I will be leaving the breaker on for the time being. My roommate's in agreement.

Comment: +1 for erring on the side of caution, but i think we cracked the case with that last comment.

Comment: I'd still get someone to open it up and confirm that. It's certainly possible, but a bit surprising... And the cost of guessing wrong could be substantial.

Comment: "**DELETE THIS! NOW!** It is **WRONG**!"

Comment: In either case it seems to be out of order in one way or another.... _broke is broke_ and it isn't going to heal itself. Replace it for $5 and your peace of mind.

Answer (score -1):

Given exactly where the flash seems to be appearing in the video ,and the fact that it appears to be circular... after reconsideration I think this may indeed be something designed in. But the only way to find out is to open things up and look for it, and/or for a maker and part number we can look up.

This ***could*** be something like a smart outlet with traditional rather than rectangular face, complaining that it can't connect to its hub or router... But we can't tell that based on what you showed us.

So, yes, turn off the power (always a good first step if you don't understand what's happening), remove the cover plate, dismount the outlet, and see if that tells you anything or if you can find identifying information. If still confused, post more pictures showing the device and the wiring and we can try to check this possibility.

It would be interesting to know if it still blinks if powered while outside the wall, with no visible spark.

Or replace it first, then look for manufacturer and model number information on the removed part and see if you can identify it as something more complicated than a single outlet.

(I don't buy night light. It doesn't throw enough light to be useful, and you shouldn't be trying to plug things in in the dark. Status light makes much more sense to me. Or a short, but if that isn't the cause this would almost have to be the answer.)